# code statement for validating an exit?

Tags: java

am having trouble trying to validate a user response to exit my app or try again(its a simple game)? when the game finishes I ask the user if they want to continue type "y" for yes or "n" for no to exit. How can I validate their response so if its neither y or n I show an error message and ask them to type it again???

This doesn't seem to worK for me???

```
if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))

           System.out.println("Error enter y for yes and n for no");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
           choice = sc.next();
```

Comment: You need to post your full code, so we can help you. This snippet doesn't explains what or where is the error.

Comment: its the logic i need help with not really the code

Comment: The problem is not on the logic, but on the code.

Comment: no it was the logic, using an "if" statement  doesn't end the program regardless of the code within, it needs to be in a "while" loop context for the code to work.

Comment: it was mearly a logic issues not a code issue that way i posted a snippet instead of my whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the

`if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`

to

`while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`

This will continue to ask them for another letter each time they don't choose the letter 'n' or 'y'.

EDIT: Also, you might want brackets around the code within the `if` (soon to be `while`) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without any full context, difficult to give a relevant answer.

But you can already test your code with curly braces around the `if` statement:

```
if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
  System.out.println("Error enter y for yes and n for no");
  System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
  choice = sc.next();
}
```

Indeed, with your current code, only the first line:

`System.out.println("Error enter y for yes and n for no");`

is taken in account by your condition.